# Examples for 축소시키는 경향

Tags: vocabulary

I just ran into the coolest sounding phrase, it just rolls right off the tongue.

> 축소시키는 경향이 있다

Google translate is saying it means a "tendency to shrink".  My question is posted in hopes of drumming up some different contexts in which saying this would fit in well.

Can we say our `옷` has a `축소시키는 경향`?  Or perhaps, is your `지갑` now short of money and so your financial fortitude has a `축소시키는 경향`?

I just realized I should probably offer up the example that brought the phrase to me.

**Example**

> 우리는 비전을 자신의 무능/제한성으로 축소시키는 경향이 있다.
>
> Our own lack of ability and inner limitations have a propensity to cause our vision to shrink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Google translate is saying it means a "tendency to shrink"

I think that could be misleading because 'shrink' in English is more commonly used in the intransitive sense, where there's no object in the sentence. However, 축소**시키는** 경향이 있다 means to cause something else to shrink - as in "the witch shrank me!".

> Can we say our 옷 has a 축소시키는 경향?

Not really, because as said above, that's saying that your clothes make something (not necessarily themselves) shrink. "clothes have a tendency to shrink" could be 옷이 축소**하는** 경향이 있다, or [as T Kim says](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/2254/64), 옷이 줄어드는 경향 which would be more common.

I'm told that most uses of this phrase would be 'academic' in tone - e.g. a newsreader saying that an event will make the economy contract, as in [T Kim's example](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/2254/64).

If you wanted a funny example (not actually common Korean), perhaps you could say:

> 그녀가 내행복을 축소시키는 경향이 있다

"she has a tendency to reduce my happiness".

Answer (score 3):

축소 means 모양이나 규모 따위가 줄어서작게 되다, which in Korean is to describe a shape or size being squeezed.

However, it may make sense if you say `옷이 축소시키는 경향` or `지갑이 축소시키는 경향`, but it is not a common way to use it among Korean native speakers.

As a first example, it makes sense if you say `옷이 줄어드는 경향` which means `clothes tend to shrink`, because for `옷` we use `줄어들다` instead of `축소`
You may say `소비를 축소시키는 경향이 있다` for second example. `소비` means `spend consume`.

줄어들다

> decrease, diminish, lessen, shrink, dwindle

축소

> reduction, cut, reduce, cut, slash, squeeze, downsize, downscale, scale down

It's the same meaning, but we use differently.

ref) http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=37975901

Comment: So if you wanted a full sentence, you could say something like 이 사건은 소비를 축소시키는 경향이 있다?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, 축소하다/시키다 is a more "serious" verb than *"shrink"*.  You would use it on stuff like: budgets, construction plans, silicon chips, etc.

Examples from the web:

> MBC의 한 PD는 “윗선의 지시로 어쩔 수 없이 정우식을 캐스팅했는데, 정우식이 연기를 못해서 대사도 줄이고 배역 자체를 **축소시킨** 일도 있었다”고 밝혔다.
>
> 최근 국내외 악재에 발목 잡힌 코스닥 지수가 반등 요소를 찾지 못하고 있는 점도 투자매력도를 떨어뜨리며 신용거래융자 규모를 **축소시킨** 것으로 분석된다.
>
> 이로 인해 실제로 새로운 고속도로 건설이 다수 폐기되거나 규모가 **축소되었다.**

For everyday use of "shrink" (e.g., clothes), you would normally use 줄어들다/줄이다, which can be used pretty much everywhere.